# Maximal and second max of chi-squared (normal squared) distribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_i$ are i.i.d.~$\log \chi^2$ where $\chi\sim N(0,1)$ distribution, in which case
$$
F(x) = \mathbb{P}\left( \log \chi^2 \le x \right)
 = 2\Phi(e^{x/2}) - 1,
$$
and
$$
f(x) = e^{x/2}\phi(e^{x/2}).
$$
Our object of study is $V = X_{(n)}-X_{(n-1)}$ which has density
$$
f_V(v) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X_{(n-1)}, X_{(n)}}(x,x+v) \,\textrm{d} x
$$
How do we compute/estimate the following probability?
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left( X_{(n)} - X_{(n-1)} \le \frac{t}{n} \right)
\end{align*}
In special it would be very interesting to obtain a large-probability result.

P.S. It is related to extreme value theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory but do we have non-asymptotic results that characterize fully the role of $n$ in the error bound?

P.P.S. I got this from my colleague but it only has the moments separately:
http://w3.math.sinica.edu.tw/bulletin_ns/20083/2008308.pdf

Comment: try to map the uniform result with a cumulant transform

Comment: Thanks! I think I obtained a heuristic answer to it, when I finish I will post the solution myself.